# Pointer Pointer leads to Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

Why can I create an array of pointers and dereference its (pointer-)elements.

```
int a = 1;
int* arr[1];

arr[0] = &a;
```

But cannot do the same with pointer to pointers:

```
int** arr2;
arr2[0] = &a;
--> Seg fault
```

Comment: You did not allocate any memory where your pointer pointer would point to and the pointer is uninitialized, so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: When you create an array, the memory is implicitly allocated on the stack so you can access it immediately. When you want to use a pointer, you need to allocate the memory yourself by using `arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int*))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### from the first part

```
int a = 1;
int* arr[1];
arr[0] = &a;
```

So `a` is `int`. `arr` is what? It is `int*[]`, an array of pointers to `int`. So the first and only element `arr[0]` is a pointer to an `int` and it is normal to assign an address of an `int` to it. The compiler is ok with that, since the operator `&` --- Address of --- assigns the address of the `int` `a` to a pointer to `int`, `arr[0]`.

#### from the second part

```
    int** arr2;
    arr2[0] = &a;
```

`arr2` is what? It is int**, a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

- `arr2` is `int**`
- so `*arr2` is `int*`, a pointer to an `int`
- and `**arr` is an `int`

`arr2` is **NOT** what? **NOT** an array, so you can not write as you did `arr[0]`.

### what you can write instead

`arr2` is `int**` so as in the first case it can get the address of a pointer to `int`. And you have an array of these here in the first part. So you for sure can write

```
    arr2 = &arr[0];
```

Since `&` will extract the address of a pointer, and `arr[0]` is a pointer to `int`. And `arr2` is `int**`, a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

#### See the output

```
toninho@DSK-2009:~/projects/um$ gcc -o tst -Wall -std=c17 pp.c
toninho@DSK-2009:~/projects/um$ ./tst
*arr[0] = 1 and **arr2 = 1
toninho@DSK-2009:~/projects/um$
```

#### of this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int     a = 1;
    int*    arr[1]; // so arr is what? int*[]

    arr[0] = &a;

    int**   arr2; // arr2 is what? int**
    //arr2[0] = &a;

    arr2 = &arr[0];

    printf("*arr[0] = %d and **arr2 = %d\n",
        *arr[0], **arr2 );
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Why can't I write `arr2[0]`? Since `x[y] == *(x + y)`, we would get `*(arr2 + 0) == *arr2`. As you said: `*arr2` ist an `int*`. I think the problem was (as mentioned by the previous comment) that I tried to dereference some kind of reserved memory because I didn't initialize my int** --> segmentation fault

Comment: read the code I posted at the end and compare. *arr2 is int* so it must, as I told you, point to a pointer. And you can as I showed you, use arr2 = &arr[0]. arr2 is int** not an array. Did you read the full text?

Comment: did you run the program I posted in your machine? Compared to your code?

Comment: Well, it is true that you did not initialize arr2. You tried in the wrong way. I showed you one legal way. Sure you can write `*arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int))`, and then assign something to it. And then free() it at the end. But is is not the point. The point is understand the mechanics of doing that and what is what, int*[] and int** for example.

Answer (score 1):

> `int** arr2;`

You don't initialize this pointer. Accessing it is undefined behavior and can/will result in crashes.

To initialize use something like `int** arr2 = malloc(<someSize> * sizeof(*arr2))`. (PS: `malloc` may return `NULL`, and you have to use `free` to return the memory).

Comment: Thanks! The pointer `arr2` is still stored in the Stack? Only pointing to the heap where my int Pointers will be stored...?

Comment: No. It's on the heap

Comment: @ChiefHan If the variable `int** arr2;` is a local variable inside a function, the pointer variable itself will be on the stack, i.e. the memory location where the address returned by `malloc` will be stored. The pointer points to the heap where the data assigned to the array element(s) will be stored.